# how to connect to pgAdmin using jdbc

Tags: java, jdbc, postgresql-9.1

I want to make a java program to access me database project which is made is pgAdmin 3 postgresql.
So how to start with that?
I am using windows.

Comment: What have you already tried? Where's the problem? Where's the *question*? Read the JDBC tutorial and the PostgreSQL JDBC driver documentation.

Comment: I tried this for mySql.But I don't know what changes I need to make for postgresQL in DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password) call and in Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").

Comment: That's covered in the PostgreSQL JDBC driver manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to connect directly to `PostgreSQL`, using a `JDBC` driver. `PgAdmin` is only a management tool that is connecting also to `PostgreSQL`. See [Connect To PostgreSQL With JDBC Driver](http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/how-do-connect-to-postgresql-with-jdbc-driver-java/) for more details.

Comment: i tried with this but It didn't hep me. Am I supposed to put both java nd jar file in same folder then run it in command prompt?

Comment: @VD3011 you need to have the `postgresql` (eg.  `java -cp ".:postgresql-9.2-1002.jdbc4.jar:other_needed_jars" your_main_class`) jar in your classpath, doesn't mater the folter, as long it's in the classpath. Note that if it's in the same directory but not in classpath it will not work.